# applying UML in PHP

Tags: php, oop, uml, iconix

most of the books that I have read on UML uses the Java language to show examples (one notable book is the ICONIX book from Apress entitle UML-Driven Object Modeling with ICONIX).
The book follows several steps using UML diagrams and then implemented in JSP. Are there methodologies to "formally" implement UML diagrams in PHP? (something like Iconix or any other UML-based dev processes) Will there be limitations when implementing my models in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about ICONIX, but I know about UML, that it doesn't have strict semantics and therefore implementation even in one language might vary, so I don't think there should be one "formal approach to implementation".